# Python - Matrix Identity multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a a dataframe a which is

```
a = [[3],
     [12],
     [15]]
```

and I want to turn it into

```
b = [[3, 0, 0],
     [0, 12,0],
     [0, 0, 15]]
```

It has been a while since high school and my matrix multiplication is a little off. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy functions

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> b = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
>>> np.fill_diagonal(b, [3, 12, 15])
>>> b
array([[ 3,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 15]])
```

If you need a DataFrame

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(b)
   0   1   2
0  3   0   0
1  0  12   0
2  0   0  15
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some lists. If you're ok with using numpy,

```
b = np.diag(a)
```

If you want to use matrix multiplication, you can do something like

```
np.dot(a, np.ones((1, 3)))
```

A `(3, 1)` matrix times a `(1, 3)` yields a `(3, 3)`.

Comment: that is even shorter!